# FRM-40501 in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

from clause query i put a query to get data from two tables check that code

```
select empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno,grade gr 
  from emp 
  left outer join salgrade on ( emp.sal between losal and hisal)
```

i also change the properties to be visible and not visible like that code

```
if   get_item_property('text_item17', visible) = 'TRUE' then
     set_item_property('text_item17', visible, property_false);  
else
     set_item_property('text_item17', visible, property_true);
     set_item_property('text_item17',enabled,property_true);
     set_item_property('text_item17',enabled,property_true);
     set_item_property('text_item17',NAVIGABLE ,property_true);
     set_item_property('text_item17',UPDATE_ALLOWED,property_true);
     set_item_property('text_item17',QUERYABLE,property_true);
     set_item_property('text_item17',UPDATE_NULL,property_true);
end if;
```

when i run the form i am getting that error that i can't update the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from dml data target type choose table and put table name then go to the item text_item17 properties change query only to yes

Answer (score 2):

Forms doesn't know which table those columns belong to, so it can't perform update.

I suggest you create a view, base data block on that view, create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger which could take care about correct inserting, updating and deleting rows from both tables.

`SET_ITEM_PROPERTY` calls you posted don't have anything to do with it (i.e. won't solve your problem).

**[EDIT]**

Saying that you'd want to *solve it without a view*, I'd suggest you not to spend too much time on that. If you open Online Forms Help and search for "Guidelines for choosing block data sources", you'll see that **FROM clause**, as a data source, allows query, but does **NOT** allow DML (inserts, updates and deletes).

Comment: i want to solve it without creating a view 
i will try first if i didn't succeed i will create a view thanks alot

Comment: my friend i did it 
i can update and delete without making a view
from dml data target type choose table and put table name 
then go to the item text_item17 properties change query only to yes 
and i works perfectly

Comment: What did you delete? There are 2 tables in your FROM clause. Did you delete a row from both of them? You should have (if - what you are saying - is correct).